# MySQL - Why does update query still run with only select privileges on a given table for a given user?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a user 'jay'@'localhost' and following are the grants for that user.

```
mysql> show grants for 'jay'@'localhost';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for jay@localhost                                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'jay'@'localhost'                                                   |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`searches` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                          |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`conversations` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                     |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`feed_entries` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                      |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`checksum_audit_logs` TO 'jay'@'localhost'               |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`local_authority_entries` TO 'jay'@'localhost'           |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`domain_terms_local_authorities` TO 'jay'@'localhost'    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`trophies` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                          |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`version_committers` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`follows` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                           |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`devise_multi_auth_authentications` TO 'jay'@'localhost' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`schema_migrations` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`orcid_profile_requests` TO 'jay'@'localhost'            |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`subject_local_authority_entries` TO 'jay'@'localhost'   |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`change_manager_changes` TO 'jay'@'localhost'            |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`receipts` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                          |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`proxy_deposit_rights` TO 'jay'@'localhost'              |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`bookmarks` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                         |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`local_authorities` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`domain_terms` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                      |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`notifications` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                     |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`single_use_links` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                  |
| GRANT SELECT ON `curate`.`users` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                                     |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `curate`.`help_requests` TO 'jay'@'localhost'                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, 'jay'@'localhost' has SELECT privileges only on the table 'curate'.'users'. But the user could still run the UPDATE query on that table.

```
mysql> select user();
+---------------+
| user()        |
+---------------+
| jay@localhost |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+------+---------+------------+------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+---------------------+
| id | email                    | encrypted_password                                           | reset_password_token | reset_password_sent_at | remember_created_at | sign_in_count | current_sign_in_at  | last_sign_in_at     | current_sign_in_ip | last_sign_in_ip | created_at          | updated_at          | guest | facebook_handle | twitter_handle | googleplus_handle | name | address | admin_area | department | title | office | chat_id | website | affiliation | telephone | avatar_file_name | avatar_content_type | avatar_file_size | avatar_updated_at | group_list | groups_last_update | user_does_not_require_profile_update | repository_id   | provider | uid  | first_name | last_name | ucstatus | ucdepartment | waived_welcome_page |
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+------+---------+------------+------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+---------------------+
|  1 | manydeposits@example.com | $2a$10$xqNke5vKUvKP8rIjtUSeD.l2L1nZpc8rx.L6mV2K2lr8XNmPpfGdy | NULL                 | NULL                   | NULL                |             2 | 2017-10-12 22:20:17 | 2017-10-12 21:45:52 | 127.0.0.1          | 127.0.0.1       | 2017-10-12 21:36:25 | 2017-10-12 22:23:21 |     0 | NULL            | NULL           | NULL              | NULL | NULL    | NULL       | NULL       |       | NULL   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      | NULL             | NULL                |             NULL | NULL              | NULL       | NULL               |                                    1 | sufia:rb68xk02w | NULL     | NULL | Many       | Deposit   | NULL     | NULL         |                   1 |
|  2 | nodeposits@example.com   | $2a$10$wTZvQjTyHqSAD9B7LYxsc.9e8W9TMZ2tVv834p6bk0mTs8E/73lOm | NULL                 | NULL                   | NULL                |             0 | NULL                | NULL                | NULL               | NULL            | 2017-10-12 21:36:28 | 2017-10-12 21:36:29 |     0 | NULL            | NULL           | NULL              | NULL | NULL    | NULL       | NULL       | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      | NULL             | NULL                |             NULL | NULL              | NULL       | NULL               |                                    1 | sufia:rb68xk04f | NULL     | NULL | No         | Deposits  | NULL     | NULL         |                NULL |
|  3 | manager@example.com      | $2a$10$j5If0Yv0bMguADFfOgRZYetE76r8rL76lSuHbyXB1j3t77bgTQa42 | NULL                 | NULL                   | NULL                |             0 | NULL                | NULL                | NULL               | NULL            | 2017-10-12 21:36:29 | 2017-10-12 21:36:30 |     0 | NULL            | NULL           | NULL              | NULL | NULL    | NULL       | NULL       | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      | NULL             | NULL                |             NULL | NULL              | NULL       | NULL               |                                    1 | sufia:rb68xk060 | NULL     | NULL | Repository | Manager   | NULL     | NULL         |                NULL |
|  4 | delegate@example.com     | $2a$10$odYs2pjBrKJIu6aVA/5SsuiyBJw27oyMQacroxG7RB1r4JHLdR5gW | NULL                 | NULL                   | NULL                |             0 | NULL                | NULL                | NULL               | NULL            | 2017-10-12 21:36:31 | 2017-10-12 21:36:32 |     0 | NULL            | NULL           | NULL              | NULL | NULL    | NULL       | NULL       | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      | NULL             | NULL                |             NULL | NULL              | NULL       | NULL               |                                    1 | sufia:rb68xk08j | NULL     | NULL | Student    | Delegate  | NULL     | NULL         |                NULL |
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+------+---------+------------+------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `users` SET `last_name` = 'Deposits', `updated_at` = '2017-10-12 22:23:21' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

What am I missing here?

Edit 1:

```
Result from @Rick James's answer.

mysql> SELECT Host, User, Db, Table_name FROM mysql.tables_priv
    ->                     WHERE table_priv LIKE '%Update%';
+-----------+------+--------+-----------------------------------+
| Host      | User | Db     | Table_name                        |
+-----------+------+--------+-----------------------------------+
| localhost | jay  | curate | version_committers                |
| localhost | jay  | curate | trophies                          |
| localhost | jay  | curate | subject_local_authority_entries   |
| localhost | jay  | curate | single_use_links                  |
| localhost | jay  | curate | searches                          |
| localhost | jay  | curate | schema_migrations                 |
| localhost | jay  | curate | receipts                          |
| localhost | jay  | curate | proxy_deposit_rights              |
| localhost | jay  | curate | orcid_profile_requests            |
| localhost | jay  | curate | notifications                     |
| localhost | jay  | curate | local_authority_entries           |
| localhost | jay  | curate | local_authorities                 |
| localhost | jay  | curate | help_requests                     |
| localhost | jay  | curate | follows                           |
| localhost | jay  | curate | feed_entries                      |
| localhost | jay  | curate | domain_terms_local_authorities    |
| localhost | jay  | curate | domain_terms                      |
| localhost | jay  | curate | devise_multi_auth_authentications |
| localhost | jay  | curate | conversations                     |
| localhost | jay  | curate | checksum_audit_logs               |
| localhost | jay  | curate | change_manager_changes            |
| localhost | jay  | curate | bookmarks                         |
+-----------+------+--------+-----------------------------------+
22 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT Host, User, Db FROM mysql.db WHERE Update_priv = 'Y';
+-----------+------+--------+
| Host      | User | Db     |
+-----------+------+--------+
| localhost |      | curate |
+-----------+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.db WHERE Update_priv = 'Y';
+-----------+------+
| Host      | User |
+-----------+------+
| localhost |      |
+-----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'jay';
+-----------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| Host      | User | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Reload_priv | Shutdown_priv | Process_priv | File_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Show_db_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Execute_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Create_user_priv | Event_priv | Trigger_priv | Create_tablespace_priv | ssl_type | ssl_cipher | x509_issuer | x509_subject | max_questions | max_updates | max_connections | max_user_connections | plugin                | authentication_string                     | password_expired | password_last_changed | password_lifetime | account_locked |
+-----------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| localhost | jay  | N           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | N          | N               | N          | N          | N            | N          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                | N          | N            | N                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password | *DD431E425EB586BD1C8173743C46FD14F76C03ED | N                | 2017-10-12 17:23:39   |              NULL | N              |
+-----------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.db   WHERE User = 'jay' AND Db = 'curate';
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE Host = 'localhost';
+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| Host      | User          | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Reload_priv | Shutdown_priv | Process_priv | File_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Show_db_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Execute_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Create_user_priv | Event_priv | Trigger_priv | Create_tablespace_priv | ssl_type | ssl_cipher | x509_issuer | x509_subject | max_questions | max_updates | max_connections | max_user_connections | plugin                | authentication_string                     | password_expired | password_last_changed | password_lifetime | account_locked |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| localhost | jay           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | N          | N               | N          | N          | N            | N          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                | N          | N            | N                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password | *DD431E425EB586BD1C8173743C46FD14F76C03ED | N                | 2017-10-12 17:23:39   |              NULL | N              |
| localhost | mysql.session | N           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | N          | N               | N          | N          | N            | Y          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                | N          | N            | N                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | N                | 2017-10-12 11:39:23   |              NULL | Y              |
| localhost | mysql.sys     | N           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | N          | N               | N          | N          | N            | N          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                | N          | N            | N                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | N                | 2017-10-12 11:39:23   |              NULL | Y              |
| localhost | root          | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            | Y                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password | *EC64FACB5BA6F06DCFB981AF3C1AC6963393B8BE | N                | 2017-10-12 11:41:57   |              NULL | N              |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.db   WHERE Host = 'localhost' AND Db = 'curate';
+-----------+--------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| Host      | Db     | User | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Execute_priv | Event_priv | Trigger_priv |
+-----------+--------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| localhost | curate |      | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y            | Y          | Y            |
+-----------+--------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.tables_priv WHERE table_name = 'users';
+-----------+--------+------+------------+----------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+
| Host      | Db     | User | Table_name | Grantor        | Timestamp           | Table_priv | Column_priv |
+-----------+--------+------+------------+----------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+
| localhost | curate | jay  | users      | root@localhost | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Select     |             |
+-----------+--------+------+------------+----------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Are you in the correct database when you run the UPDATE?

Comment: Are any `VIEWs` or Stored Routines involved?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes.

Comment: @RickJames I believe not. Basically, it's a Ruby on Rails application with MySQL as DB. Rake task creates the database and all the tables required for the application. Let me know how/what to look for. 

Thanks to you both for prompt replies.

Comment: Which specific version of 5.7?  Do you have any authentication plugins?

Comment: Server version: 5.7.19 Homebrew

Answer (score 0):

Peruse these to see if he is getting in some other way:

```
SELECT Host, User, Db, Table_name FROM mysql.tables_priv
                    WHERE table_priv LIKE '%Update%';
SELECT Host, User, Db FROM mysql.db WHERE Update_priv = 'Y';
SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.db WHERE Update_priv = 'Y';
```

Or...

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'jay';
SELECT * FROM mysql.db   WHERE User = 'jay' AND Db = 'curate';
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE Host = 'localhost';
SELECT * FROM mysql.db   WHERE Host = 'localhost' AND Db = 'curate';
SELECT * FROM mysql.tables_priv WHERE table_name = 'users';
```

Wildcards (eg, `'%'`) may take precedence.

Comment: I'll, once I get back to my work laptop tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @RickJames `SHOW GRANTS FOR ...` should capture everything from all the permissions tables, shouldn't it?  Even an updatable view with `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` shouldn't allow itself to be written to by an invoker without the invoker having privileges against the view.

Comment: I think that is the potential flaw.  And, I suggest it is deliberate for a Stored Routine after, say, jay's request has been checked.

Comment: @RickJames updated my question with the query results that you just asked me to post. There is a user ' '.

Comment: Hmmm...  `SHOW GRANTS FOR ''@'localhost';`